# SOFR Futures and impact on short-end dollar swaps and front-end notes

Tags: interest-rate-swap, treasuries, sofr, rates

Suppose there is an exogenous event that triggers SOFR futures to be repriced lower.
For simplicity, lets say the SOFR futures mostly impacted are whites/reds.

Since USD swaps are priced off of the SOFR curve, would it naturally follow that 1y~2y swap rates will also be repriced higher?

Additionally, given the discounting curve is repriced higher, would it follow that T-bill prices and 2y T-note prices would be repriced lower?

And most importantly, what kind of impact would this have on the front-end swap spread (swaps vs cash yield)?  I would imagine the degree of sell-off would be roughly equal, meaning that swap spreads would not change, unless there is a large difference between the flow for swaps vs flow for cash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to all of your questions.  USD swaps vs SOFR futures express almost identical risks, except for the 'convexity adjustment' which is small to first order.  Secondly, it is almost certain that on a day where sofr futures reprice lower, so will the price of 1 and 2 yr Treasuries (because SOFR is literally the financing rate for Treasuries).  The third question, which probes further into this relationship, has some nuance.  Sofr futures and Treasury yields can move slightly differently, due to various effects.  For example, the Treasury unexpectedly decides to issue more 1yr and 2yr Treasuries -> they cheapen slightly versus Sofr.  Or, the 2yr Treasury goes on 'special' in the repo market (meaning, it has a lower financing cost than other Treasuries) -> the 2yr note becomes more expensive relative to Sofr).  But these relative moves tend to be small versus the outright moves in each instrument.